# RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.xyz.in a.php?id=%1

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

whats wrong in it, please suggest.

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.xyz.in a.php?id=%1
```

while hitting to `a.php?id=something`, I am getting `yzx.xyz.in` but server DNS address could not be found.
Please suggest me what's the solution.
Thank you.

Comment: You are missing a `^` at the beginning of your rewrite rule

Comment: Unclear... and `%1` refers to first capturing group of a `RewriteCond` directive. To back-reference a `RewriteRule` capturing group prepend the number with a `$`: `$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to .htaccess file then rewrite this code.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?id=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?id=([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+?)(?:\.html)?$ /index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```